# Django models.DecimalField issues with type and value conversion

Tags: django, django-orm

Let's say you have a model like this:

```
class Example(models.Model):
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
```

I can do the following with no issue:

```
x = Example()
x.amount = 1.23456
x.save()
print(x.amount, type(x.amount))  # outputs '1.23456 <type 'float'>'
```

If I load back the object I find that `x.amount` is now equal to `Decimal('1.23')`.

So, my issue is, at any given moment with any given instance of `Example` the `amount` attribute may contain a `Decimal`, a `float`, an `integer`, or something else that can be coerced into a `Decimal`.  Also, the value may not yet be rounded to 2 decimal places so the value may change after saving and loading back from the database.  As well, a statement like `x.amount + Decimal('1')` may work or may throw an exception about combining `float` with `Decimal`.

Has anyone developed a replacement for `models.DecimalField` that mitigates these issues by immediately performing conversions and rounding when assigning a value instead of how it currently functions?  Or, alternatively, a model that throws an error if an improper type is assigned or one that would be rounded on save?  (I suspect I could write my own, but I was hoping I could find someone else's work that's already been fairly well tested and seen actual use)

Comment: What you think about [`obj.refresh_from_db()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#refreshing-objects-from-database)? If you want to be sure it is necessary. It is e.g. possible with MySQL that you save a string longer than `max_length` of the CharField and the last characters are lost, while PostgreSQL server raises an exception and sqlite allows to save and read a longer string. The replacement that you mean can therefore depend on the database backend. It is possible to save an object in one database and then to save in another db: `obj.save(using='other_db')`

Comment: I guess that this style not to convert early could be a convention that has arisen before migrations and continues due to compatibility.

Comment: @hynekcer - Yes, the db backend throws an unknown factor in.  For example, I think some sqlite versions don't support Decimal and end up using floats.  So, I can't see this ever being included in the Django base, but I was hoping someone else had written something I could use since I know I'm only using Postgresql and the only issue is the save/retrieve from db will convert to Decimal and round.
The `refresh_from_db` would only work if I first save, but sometimes need to work with the object and it's values before saving.